# Bash script, split Konsole tab to 2x2 grid and run a command on each

Tags: konsole

Is there a way to use a bash script to create a konsole with 4 parts (2 left and 2 rights) in the same tab.

It should also run 4 different scripts on each part.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried [Terminator](https://www.ghacks.net/2010/10/21/multi-view-terminal-with-terminator/)?

Comment: looks like I don't have another choice, it won't work be default in Konsole, Terminator is good tho. thx

Comment: You could also look into terminal multiplexers, like tmux.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it

```
#! /bin/bash

cmd1="echo 1"
cmd2="echo 2"
cmd3="echo 3"
cmd4="echo 4"

echo '{
    "Orientation": "Horizontal",
    "Widgets": [
        {
            "Orientation": "Vertical",
            "Widgets": [
                {
                    "SessionRestoreId": 0
                },
                {
                    "SessionRestoreId": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Orientation": "Vertical",
            "Widgets": [
                {
                    "SessionRestoreId": 0
                },
                {
                    "SessionRestoreId": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}' > /tmp/Konsole2x2layout.json
konsole --layout /tmp/Konsole2x2layout.json &
sleep 2

service="$(qdbus | grep -B1 konsole | grep -v -- -- | sort -t"." -k2 -n | tail -n 1)"

qdbus $service /Sessions/1 org.kde.konsole.Session.runCommand "${cmd1}"
qdbus $service /Sessions/2 org.kde.konsole.Session.runCommand "${cmd2}"
qdbus $service /Sessions/3 org.kde.konsole.Session.runCommand "${cmd3}"
qdbus $service /Sessions/4 org.kde.konsole.Session.runCommand "${cmd4}"
```